# prevent cross-site scripting in java

Tags: java, jsp, xss

There is an old web project that i have to maintain and make some development. I've scanned it with fortify tool and it found lots of defects about cross-site scripting. Project contains a lot of jsps and servlets. Doing validation in each field is almost impossible because of the count of jsp files. What is the easiest way to prevent xss in an old project.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy answers here.  You can (as Sridhar mentions) override the getParameter and do encoding there, and that will provide a lot of coverage, but its the wrong place to be encoding - encoding should be done when you know where the value is being used.  This will resolve some security issues but lead to HTML encoding in areas that its not appropriate (DB, Javascript...) as well as double encoding of values.

The correct answer is to go through the Fortify results and encode the areas that tainted output is being sent to HTML, javascript....  Check out OWASP for encoders.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a CustomRequestWrapper class which extends HttpServletRequestWrapper, where in you can override methods like getParameter, getParameterValues etc

Do HTML entity encoding / escaping to prevent XSS..

Just add a filter which can route all the requests to your CustomRequestWrapper. So that they will hit your Xss prevention code.

Add a filter xml to Web.xml

and in your customRequestWrapper do  the following,

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
    throws IOException, ServletException {
    chain.doFilter(new CustomRequestWrapper((HttpServletRequest) request), response);
}
```